# MVC 5 form with no action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I want to ask if i have this form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

where will the form be sent? To the current controller or? (since it's action="" (null))

Comment: Yes. It will post back to the current url

Comment: @Shyju ty very much